# Python -Using wget with post data -gett error 400 bad request

Tags: python, wget

I'm using python 2.7 with windows 8
I'm trying to run wget as below:

```
APIWGET = ["c:\\wget\\wget.exe","--post-data={ user_name: admin, password: 

Admin11!}","--output-document="+APIJSONOUTPUT + 'APIJSONResponse_' + TimeNow 

+ '.txt', "--save-headers", "http....."]
```

I have issue with the post data..
hope that i'm doing it right,
i basically run the api and need to add "payload" the user\password" and get the error 400 (happened only when i added the post data)
is it post data i need to use here? if so what is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: I guess your webserver expects a JSON payload. What you wrote is not valid JSON. Try with `{user_name: "admin", password: "Admin11!"}`

Comment: Your post data is not valid JSON document.

Comment: I tried the :{user_name: "admin", password: "Admin11!"}

Comment: got unexected token admin and admin11! , because of the "" ""

Comment: when  i run it in Rest Client, the Payload works when it written like this:

Comment: {

  "user_name": "admin",

  "password": "Admin11!"

}

Comment: you cannot include double quotes inside a double quoted string. Use this: `'--post-data={ "user_name": "admin", "password": "Admin11!" }'`

Comment: Sorry, still error 400 after last suggestion-'--post-data={ "user_name": "admin", "password": "Admin11!" }'

Comment: It appears that wget only supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not arbitrary data

Comment: So any other suggestions

Comment: don't use wget :) Python comes with [urllib](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html), use that instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not strictly answer to your question, but I'll strongly recommend using native Python libraries, especially [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Simple post request may be made as simply as:

```
import requests
url = "http://..."
r = requests.post(url, data={"user_name": "admin", "password": "Admin11!"})
r.raise_for_status()
# access response as text
r.text
# or json
r.json()
# access server response header
r.headers
```

More details for sending post requests may be found in [official docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: Hi. I have tried using urllib and getting error 400.can you tell me what is wrong now :( import urllib
            import urllib2
            url = 'http://x.x.x.x:8080/lms/v1/identity/tokens'
            data = urllib.urlencode({"user_name": "admin",  "password": "Admin11!"})
            req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            d = response.read()
            print d